# using hotlink prevention

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

I'm wondering how to target the picture in this following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://dooomain.com/.*$     [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.dooomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*.jpg$ -                           [L]
```

not really sure where I have to insert the jpg file!! is it in the web root folder or where?

Thanks

**Update #1**

ok, maybe I found something to my answer, but not sure so please guys correct me if I'm wrong...

here is the code I should add instead of the last line in my main post:

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ https://www.mydooomain.com/pic.gif [R,L]
```

and I need to place the picture in the root in this case, is that right???

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last rule above is fine. But `rewritecond` can be done in a single line.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(?:$|http://domain.com|http://www.domain.com) [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ https://www.mydomain.com/pic.gif [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Thinking. That was very helpful. will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: @Digitalsite, you might also consider [R=301,L] or make sure that the Expires on `pic.gif` is access plus 1 month min, if you are getting at lot of these.

Comment: yes @TerryE is right. `R=301` will minimize some if not all requests.