# Prevent hotlinking image files

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, hotlinking

I want to avoid hotlinking images. Basing of this answer: [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408197/using-hotlink-prevention) I've tried to add the next snippet code into `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?itransformer.es/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ htttp://itransformer.es [R,L]
```

but it is not working. When I try to access the images putting the path in the navigation bar, I can access. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're explicitly ignoreing referers that are blank. When you type the URL in your navigation bar, there is no referer, therefore `%{HTTP_REFERER}` is blank and it will **fail** the `!^$` pattern. Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?itransformer.es/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|wbmp)$ http://itransformer.es [R,L]
```

Also, you have an extra "t" in your `htttp://`

Comment: @ManoloSalsas [Works fine for me in my blank htaccess file](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rAEdP.png).

Comment: Yes! Seems I had to reload the URL. Anyway seems to work perfect. Other vulnerability avoided. Thank you.