# How to make only index.php to be visited

Tags: redirect

What is the best way to make only index.php able to be visited.
For example the link is  domain.com.images/1.jpg  and it leads to a specific image. And when user goes on that link, how i can make him go directly to index.php without being able to open the image as link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent hotlinking image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656103/prevent-hotlinking-image-files)

Comment: I used like 40 different codes in .htaccess but none of them does anything. I use cpanel

Comment: They way of doing that is using .htaccess, check that you have enabled the use of .htaccess and that you put `RewriteEngine on` before the rules.